my code.hs python script gives me unusual errors
i cant figure this out i need help. i am new to python on my quest to learn as many coding languages as i can (this is my third) and was writing a script because i got bored and had nothing better to do when a strange error happened. please send help.
i was writing a python script in code.hs to make a turtle try and find its way to the upper left hand side of the screen. but i kept getting an error that my path1 global variable was not yet declared when it was used on line 133 and after weeks of trying i am giving up and putting it on here to see if anyone can fix my problem.
import random
print(random.uniform(-10000, 10000))

speed(0)
path1 = 0
path2 = 0
pathturn1 = 0
pathturn2 = 0
lasty = 0
lastx = 0
randist1 = 0
randist2 = 0
ranturn1 = 0
ranturn2 = 0
ranchange1 = 0
ranchange2 = 0
ranchange3 = 0    
ranchange4 = 0
p1c = 0            
p2c = 0            
pt1c = 0            
pt2c = 0

def first_line():
    randist1 = random.uniform(-150, 150)
    randist2 = random.uniform(-150, 150)
    ranturn1 = random.uniform(-360, 360)
    ranturn2 = random.uniform(-360, 360)

    left(ranturn1)
    forward(randist1)
    left(ranturn2)
    forward(randist2)
    
    pos_check1()
    
    penup()
    setposition(0, 0)
    seth(0)
    pendown()
    

def pos_check1():
    if xcor() >= 100:
        if ycor() >= 100:      
            print("hit!")
            clear()
            path1 = randist1
            path2 = randist2
            pathturn1 = ranturn1
            pathturn2 = ranturn2
            lastx = xcor()
            lasty = ycor()
            
            penup()
            setposition(0, 0)
            seth(0)
            pendown()
            
            Increment()
        else:
            penup()
            setposition(0, 0)
            seth(0)
            pendown()
            
            first_line()
    else:
        penup()
        setposition(0, 0)
        seth(0)
        pendown()
            
        first_line()

def Increment():
    print("increment")
    
    ranchange1 = random.uniform(-30, 30)
    ranchange2 = random.uniform(-30, 30)
    ranchange3 = random.uniform(-5, 5)
    ranchange4 = random.uniform(-5, 5)
    p1c = path1 + ranchange1
    p2c = path2 + ranchange2
    pt1c = pathturn1 + ranchange3
    pt2c = pathturn2 + ranchange4

    left(pt1c)
    forward(p1c)
    left(pt2c)
    forward(p2c)
    
    if xcor() >= lastx:
        if ycor() >= lasty:
            path1 = p1c
            path2 = p2c
            pathturn1 = pt1c
            pathturn2 = pt2c

first_line()


You have defined a local variable path1 inside the function; this is not the same object as the path1 defined at the start of the code: see Python scope rules. You need to designate the name inside the function as being global. But please note: it is bad practice to use global variables in this way - pass and return values to functions. See guidance

thank you i did not know that i came to python from java script where global variables are highly encouraged
